# Mapping concrete types

Tags: go, types, maps

What is the idiomatic way to define something like `map[type]interface{}`?

As far I can see the **type** (as keyword) is not something *comparable* so can not be used as a key in a map. Maybe I'm going in the wrong way, so U would accept any suggestion.

TL;DR;

Example motivation

Let's assume in the application model I have **type** called **Person**, being stored in a *table* named **"person"** of a *rdbms*.

If I would like to link the entity object **Person** to the the **table name**. Things that by definition doens't come together, so it is wise to avoid polluting the Person struct with "not-naturally-related" (this is where my java-OO-based mind appears) [pointer|value]-recieve methods, so a map could be in handy here, right? (maps are great for associating things from differents worlds or sets, right?)

```
var tableNameByType map[type]string = map[type]string{
      Person: "person",
}
```

This statement causes the compiler to yell at me complaining about `expected type, found 'type'`. I have tried used instead of type, interface{} and struct, with no better results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reflect.Type` as the key:

```
var tableNameByType map[reflect.Type]string = map[reflect.Type]string{
    reflect.TypeOf(Person{}): "person",
}
```

You can get the name for a type using:

```
name := tableNameByType[reflect.TypeOf(Person{})]
```

... or the name for value `v` using:

```
name := tableNameByType[reflect.ValueOf(v).Type()]
```

You can avoid instantiating the struct value by replacing `reflect.TypeOf(Person{})` with `reflect.TypeOf((*Person)(nil)).Elem()` in the above code.

Comment: Is a good workaround! i wonder if there is no way to avoid instanciating a new struct (`Person{}`) of the given type in order to get the type? In that case a recommended approach would be to have an internal struct of type Person instanciated (i.e. in universe block golang but not public) that as "living representation of the type"?

Comment: Thanks @ThunderCat!! very valuable info you share! No idea what kind of vuddu magic is `reflect.TypeOf((*Person)(nil)).Elem()` but thanks for the idea!

Comment: Let's call this tecnique "type based on living representation" shall we :D. You need to create an instance of the given type (pointer or value) in order to get the type.

Comment: please, allow me to maintain this question open for a little bit more  (in order to be able get more answers). If no more information is provided to this question this shall be the correct answer. As "type based on living represantion" is the idiomatic way to map types (until golang-dev-team implements comparision of types "as-is")